# iOS Version Target query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: 1) current iOS versions and  2) target iOS version and wanted to get a target iOS version for each version, how should I go about doing this?

| iOS Version |
| --- |
| 11.0.0 |
| 12.0.1 |
| 13.5.0 |
| 16.4.1 |
| 17.1.0 |

| Target iOS Version |
| --- |
| 12.5.7 |
| 15.8.0 |
| 17.2.0 |

Goal:
The goal was for each current version to have a target version to be matched with, i.e. if the current version is 12.0.1, the target version would be 12.5.7 but if the current version exceeds 12.5.7, for example 13.5.0 then the target version would be 15.8.0 but not the latest 17.2.0.

| iOS Version | Target iOS Version |
| --- | --- |
| 11.0.0 | 12.5.7 |
| 12.0.1 | 12.5.7 |
| 13.5.0 | 15.8.0 |
| 16.4.1 | 17.2.0 |
| 17.1.0 | 17.2.0 |

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any relationship between these two tables. Is the logic to just sort them both by version number and then set them side-by-side and hope they line up?

Comment: The goal was for each current version to have a target version to be matched with, i.e. if the current version is 12.0.1, the target version would be 12.5.7 but if the current version exceeds 12.5.7, for example 13.5.0 then the target version would be 15.8.0 but not the latest 17.2.0.

Comment: Got it. For each iOS version, find the next highest Target iOS version.

Comment: Why are there duplicates in the  Target iOS Version table?

Comment: My mistake when typing this, edited to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *correlated subquery* in the select list is probably the most basic solution:

```
select c.[iOS Version],
       (select min([Target iOS Version]) from targetosversionstable
        where [Target iOS Version] > c.[iOS Version]) as [Target iOS Version]
from currentosversionstable c
```

Answer (score -1):

One method is a `cartesian join` and getting the min(t.version) greater than each version.

```
select c.version, min(t.version) as target_ios_version
  from ios_version c, target_ios_version t
 where t.version > c.version
 group by c.version
```

```
--or using Cross Join
select c.version, min(t.version) as target_ios_version
  from ios_version c
 cross join target_ios_version t
 where t.version > c.version
 group by c.version
```

| version | target_ios_version |
| --- | --- |
| 11.0.0 | 12.5.7 |
| 12.0.1 | 12.5.7 |
| 13.5.0 | 15.8.0 |
| 16.4.1 | 17.2.0 |
| 17.1.0 | 17.2.0 |

Comment: Works well, but I'd use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.